# mysql select not exists child in same table

Tags: mysql, select

exampletable

```
+----+--------------------+------------------+
| id | name               | parent           |
+----+--------------------+------------------+
|  1 | menu1              | 0                |
|  2 | menu2              | 1                |
|  3 | menu3              | 0                |
|  4 | menu4              | 3                |
|  5 | menu5              | 0                |
|  6 | menu6              | 4                |
|  7 | menu7              | 4                |
|  8 | menu8              | 7                |
+----+--------------------+------------------+
```

i want to select have not child row in same table.

Thanks.

Comment: fasle question i want to select not have child row sorry.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "child row"? When you say you don't want it to be in the same table, do you mean you want another table similarly linked? Please could you expand your question, and perhaps show what you are getting and what you were expecting?

Comment: edited now i want to see not have child menu

Comment: i want to select menu which has not child (submenu)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table pc
(   -- parent child
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    parent int not null
);
insert pc(name,parent) values ('menu1',0),('menu2',1),('menu3',0),('menu4',3),('menu5',0),('menu6',4),('menu7',4),('menu8',7);

Select id,name from pc where id not in (select parent from pc)
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  2 | menu2 |
|  5 | menu5 |
|  6 | menu6 |
|  8 | menu8 |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: `not in` can be dangerous in cases when null is in the result set ..[of select id from Table]  ...(a warning for when he or someone does such, quite easy to imagine). Use `not exists`. Plus `select id from table1` just did a tablescan. I would show an example of the problem but people's eyes would glaze over :)

Answer (score 0):

This is little bit messy but it will work :

```
SELECT t3.id,t3.name,t3.parent
FROM   test t3 
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t1.parent from test t1 inner join test t2 on t1.id = t2.parent) t4 on t3.id = t4.id
WHERE  t4.id IS NULL;
```

Output :

```
+----+-------+--------+
| id | name  | parent |
+----+-------+--------+
|  2 | menu2 | 1      |
|  5 | menu5 | 0      |
|  6 | menu6 | 4      |
|  8 | menu8 | 7      |
+----+-------+--------+
```

Comment: i dont have two table

Comment: @mdilaver : also in my query I have considered only one table "test". which two table you are talking about ?

Comment: t1 , t2, t3 and t4 table.

Comment: @mdilaver : t1, t2, t3 are the alias of the table "test" and t4 is the result table of inner query. You just have to replace "test" with your tableName, nothing else.

Comment: i have just one table : exampletable

Comment: @mdilaver : just copy my query and replace "test" with "exampletable" like `SELECT t3.id,t3.name,t3.parent
FROM   exampletable t3 
LEFT   JOIN (SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t1.parent from exampletable t1 inner join exampletable t2 on t1.id = t2.parent) t4 on t3.id = t4.id
WHERE  t4.id IS NULL;`

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't1.name' in 'field list' :)))))

Comment: @mdilaver : Is table "exampletable" have columnName 'name' ? Make sure your table contain all specified columnNames.